# Have distance from A to B, C, D - How to get latitude and longitude?

Tags: stata, distance, latitude-longitude

I am not a geographer or the like, so please excuse if I should know better. But my question is: Is it possible to get the latitude and longitude of certain places from distance data?

More precisely, I have the great-circle distance in kilometers from various places to Berlin. Can I somehow decompose this distance data into latitude and longitude?

(FYI I am an economic historian and I work with the software package Stata.)

Comment: Well if you only have distance from place X to Berlin you can only define a circle around Berlin on which that place can be...

Answer (score 1):

Yep, but the answer depends on how accurate you want to be.

Quick and easy, but not exact: just assume the earth is a sphere, treat the lat/lon as spherical coordinates (using a fixed 6373km radius), perform the translation using normal 3D euclidean geometry techniques, and convert back to lat/lon at the end. A good summary of the calculations necessary is [here](https://www.johndcook.com//lat_long_details.html), but in summary:

*Oh dear, no Latex on this site! Screenshots from the math subsite is best I could do sorry.*

[image]

If you already have arc length, then rearrange the equation to solve for your unknown. You'll also need to know the angle of your arc to solve for two unknowns, lat and long.

If you need to be exact, you'll need to take into account the non-spherical Earth. That means the length in meters of a degree latitude depends on the latitude.

As described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_system#Expressing_latitude_and_longitude_as_linear_units):

[image]

Work with those equations and perhaps ask another more specific question if you get stuck. This current site is best if you have a programming question and the https://math.stackexchange.com site is best if you have a maths question.

Comment: Please mark this answer as a solution to the question then.